# Bootstrap- resize heigh of element according the width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I use bootstrap to create responsive layout.
Here is the jsF  http://jsfiddle.net/sarit8/8vqop6dz/

I have few issues:

1. I try to use a script which apparently doesn't work.
2. In case I add the following static style I can see the squares but there are too much spaces between some of them , and page is not responsive:

```
.black{background-color:black; float:left; width:100%;}
.black.double{height: 490px;}
```

Comment: Why do you combine both jQuery and pure JavaScript. Confuses right?

Comment: Use this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8vqop6dz/3/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use just css to achieve the desired result, no js necessary,

http://jsfiddle.net/8vqop6dz/1/

```
.black {
  padding-top: 56%;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.black > * {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

this works because in css margin and padding percentages are set relative to the width of an element rather than the height. so when you say the padding-top is 56%, that means 56 percent of the width of the element.

Comment: @synthet1c- there are still issues of responsive , can't see the double div which suppose to be in the end of row 2-3, the wrong places in the last row, and the heigh is not equal to the width. Besides the size of the big squares is too big.

Comment: @saritRotshild you can change the height of the boxes by changing the padding-top percentage. for double you would just add a class for `.black.double { padding-top: $doubleThePadding }`,

Comment: @synthet1c- according your code the size of the squares is not correct. I the first line all the height should be as same as the width and the 3 "big" sque should be the same height of the first row